ubuntu 24.04 jsut cached the memory over time and never free it to new applications opened, after a while freezed up to no memory left
It had been two weeks monitoring my Ubuntu desktop by btop to figure out what caused this problem, but no luck.
Ubuntu 24.04 just keeps cached memory when nothing is open, then uses all swap space and also never frees it for new apps. After a while, it may freeze due to no memory left. I know Linuxatemymemory and that stuff, but it's different. I used Ubuntu mainly for over three years now, and never has this happened like that.
Can you see that systemd just uses 3g and the whole memory is just cached.

I tried to increase vm.vfs_cache_pressure, but nothing is different.
My sysctl.conf:
vm.oom-kill = 1 
vm.swappiness = 10   
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 300  

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. GF63 Thin 10SCSR
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i5-10200H × 8
Graphics:                                    Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT1)
Graphics 1:                                  NV167
Disk Capacity:                               512.1 GB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            E16R4IMS.10B
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-48-generic

